# LAG of MIN in SQL Analytic

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, analytics, window-functions

I have a table containing employees id, year id, client id, and the number of sales. For example:

```
 --------------------------------------
  id_emp | id_year | sales | client id
 --------------------------------------
    4    |    1    |   14  |    1
    4    |    1    |   10  |    2
    4    |    2    |   11  |    1
    4    |    2    |   17  |    2
```

For a employee, I want to obtain rows with the minimum sales per year and the minimum sales of the previous year.

One of the queries I tried is the following:

```
select distinct 
  id_emp,
  id_year, 
  MIN(sales) OVER(partition by id_emp, id_year) AS min_sales,
  LAG(min(sales), 1) OVER(PARTITION BY id_emp, id_year
                              ORDER BY id_emp, id_year) AS previous
 from facts
where id_emp = 4
group by id_emp, id_year, sales;
```

**I get the result:**

```
 -------------------------------------    
  id_emp | id_year | sales | previous
 -------------------------------------
    4    |    1    |   10  |  (null)
    4    |    1    |   10  |    10
    4    |    2    |   11  |  (null)
```

**but I expect to get:**

```
 -------------------------------------
  id_emp | id_year | sales | previous
 -------------------------------------
    4    |    1    |   10  |  (null)
    4    |    2    |   11  |    10
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Why do you partition by year in the LAG function if you want to get the previous year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5876f7/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_SALES ( id_emp, id_year, sales, client_id ) AS
          SELECT 4, 1, 14, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 1, 10, 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2, 11, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2, 17, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ID_EMP,
       ID_YEAR,
       SALES AS SALES,
       LAG( SALES ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID_EMP ORDER BY ID_YEAR ) AS PREVIOUS
FROM   (
  SELECT e.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id_emp, id_year ORDER BY sales ) AS RN
  FROM   EMPLOYEE_SALES e
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT ID_EMP,
       ID_YEAR,
       MIN( SALES ) AS SALES,
       LAG( MIN( SALES ) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID_EMP ORDER BY ID_YEAR ) AS PREVIOUS
FROM   EMPLOYEE_SALES
GROUP BY ID_EMP, ID_YEAR
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5876f7/8/1) - Both give the same output**:

```
| ID_EMP | ID_YEAR | SALES | PREVIOUS |
|--------|---------|-------|----------|
|      4 |       1 |    10 |   (null) |
|      4 |       2 |    11 |       10 |
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

```
select id_emp, id_year, min(sales) as min_sales,
    lag(min(sales)) over (partition by id_emp order by id_year) as prev_year_min_sales
from facts
where id_emp = 4
group by id_emp, id_year;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get your desired output using **ROW_NUMBER()** and **LAG()** analytic functions.

For example,

**Table**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

    ID_EMP    ID_YEAR      SALES  CLIENT_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         4          1         14          1
         4          1         10          2
         4          2         11          1
         4          2         17          2
```

**Query**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT t.*,
  3      row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY id_emp, id_year ORDER BY sales) rn
  4    FROM t
  5    )
  6  SELECT id_emp,
  7    id_year ,
  8    sales ,
  9    lag(sales) over(order by sales) previous
 10  FROM DATA
 11  WHERE rn =1;

    ID_EMP    ID_YEAR      SALES   PREVIOUS
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         4          1         10
         4          2         11         10
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you are using sales column in your group by statement. 
Try to remove it and just use

```
  GROUP BY id_emp,id_year
```